# What's the optimum configuration for sub second query latency in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have imported nodes.tsv ( 350MB, 18M rows, 3 cols) and rels.tsv ( 5GB, 150M rows, 2 cols) using the batch-importer script.
These are my batch.properties file entries

- •    neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=250M
  •    neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1000M
  •    neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=10M
  •    neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=500M
  •    neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=500M
  •    neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=215M
  •    dump_configuration=true

I have turned on auto update and auto indexing in ne04j.properties as follows

- •    allow_store_upgrade=true •  node_auto_indexing=true
  •    node_keys_indexable=name,title •    relationship_auto_indexing=true
  •    relationship_keys_indexable=sent_date,has_read

I'm using neo4j 2.2 version on 64 bit windows server that has 1 TB SSD and 256GB ram.
What's the configuration for batch importer and neo4j server that I should use for maximum query and data loading peformance?
This query for ex: is timing out in the browser

```
MATCH ()-[r:BELONGS_TO]->() RETURN r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With millions of nodes that query might be slow no matter what you do, though with the amount of memory you have available maybe it wouldn't be a big deal.  This is a good guide for calculating memory settings:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/

While you're playing, I would set the query timeout on the server so that your queries can't jam up the server and force you to need to restart it:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html

You might try starting with `LIMIT` clauses on your queries so that you can get an idea for how the performance degrades as the LIMIT increases.

If you can possibly find a way to limit your query based on node selects that would also be helpful, especially if you can do it by a label or by a label/property combination (which you can index).

Lastly, I would try using `EXPLAIN` in the web console to get an idea for how your queries will be executed:

http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html

Also you can use `PROFILE`, though that will run the query, so you'll need to be a bit more careful there.  You can probably use the `LIMIT` here too to play and see how things work

Comment: Thanks Brian for the info. My next step is to profile the queries. What's strange is that my overall database folder size is 11.6GB after insertion and index creation. So all of this can easily reside in the RAM I have. And so I'm surprised that queries are timing out for a dB that can reside entirely in memory. I want to know if there are any props I should increase in batch.properties or neo4j

Comment: I think the main problem is that queries need to anchor on nodes, and if you're just querying on `()` then it essentially has to search the entire database and check every relationship on every node for `BELONGS_TO` relationships

Answer (score 2):

If you have that much RAM:

Your memory mapping config is wrong for 2.2

use only this setting:
`dbms.pagecache.memory=20G``

and then provide neo4j with 24G heap in neo4j-wrapper.conf

Use Neo4j enterprise which scales much better.

Disable the auto-indexes they are not used for what you're doing.

Your query doesn't make sense for any use-case:

`MATCH ()-[r:BELONGS_TO]->() RETURN r`

Sub-second graph queries always start at a set of concrete start-points (retrieved with an index lookup) and then traverse out from those starting points.

Global scan queries like your's will just pull all data in memory and inefficiently work over it.

Esp. if you return so much data you can't assume sub-second performance. The data volume alone will kill it.

So figure out a label + property-values that you want to start from and then write the query that traverses out from those start points.

If you want to have sub-second on something you're doing you have to go down to the Java API and aggregate there, e.g. with a server extension:

```
int counter=0;
for (Relationship r : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db)) {
   if (r.hasType(Types.BELONGS_TO)) counter++;
}
return counter;
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I can change the setting  of page cage memory in neo4j.propeties files. Where is the . conf file located that I can modify the heap size of vm? Couldn't find any . conf file in my db folder

Comment: it's in the conf folder, if you are on windows check the "Options" button of the starter-app.